# Proof on order of element of cyclic group must divide the order of the group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

I am proving the following problem. I finished proving it but do not know is it sufficient enough.

> Problem: Prove that the order of an element in a cyclic group $G$ must
> divide the order of the group.

My original proof:

> Let the order of $G$ be $n$, and the generator of $G$ be $a$, then $a^n=e$. Then, for each element $b\in G, \exists k, m \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $|b|=k$ and $b=a^m$. It must follow that:
>
> $b^{k}=(a^{m})^{k}$ $\implies$ $e=a^{mk}$ $\implies$$a^n=a^{mk}$ $\implies$ $n=mk$.
>
> Since $m\in \mathbb{Z}$, then $k|n$.

My edited proof:

Let the order of $G$ be $n$, and the generator of $G$ be $a$, then $a^n=e$. Then, for each element $b\in G, \exists k, m \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $|b|=k$ and $b=a^m$. It must follow that:

$k=\frac{n}{gcd(n,m)} \implies n=(k)gcd(n,m)$

Since $gcd(n,m)\in \mathbb{N}$, then $k|n$.

My question is that I have seen lots of people used Division Algorithm to prove this, but it is only when the element is the generator, here it is any element. Yet, I don't know my prove is sufficient or not. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is wrong because you state that $a^n=a^{mk}\implies n=mk$. Why do you think that this is true?

However, $a^n=a^{mk}=e\implies n\mid mk$, but this is not enough to deduce that $k\mid n$, which is what you want to prove.

Comment: That makes sense, I knew something was wrong with my proof. Thank you. Also, can I use the $gcd$ to approach this? or is there any other way to do this.

Comment: @Harry I think the using the $\operatorname{lcm}$ is a good approach here.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to use $lcm$. Do you mind looking at my edited proof to see this approach work or not?

Comment: @Harry I don't see any justification of the assertion that $k=\frac n{\gcd(m,n)}$.

Comment: It's from the theorem states that if $G$ is cyclic and has a generator $a$ with order $n$, then for any element $b \in G, b=a^{k}$. The order of $b$ is $n/d$ where $d=gcd(n,k)$.

Comment: @Harry All right. Of course, if you are allowed to use that theorem, everything becomes quite easy.

Answer (score 0):

According to your hypothesis that $|G|=n \in {\mathbb N}~$ . Therefore , $G$ is a finite group.

Now for each $a\in G~$  ,$~\langle a\rangle$ forms a subgroup of the group $G$ .Then we see on account of the Lagrange theorem that $|\langle a\rangle |~|~|G|,$ that is ,$|\langle a\rangle |$ is a divisor of $~|G|~.$

Keep in mind that this proof holds for all group $G$ , and hence of course the cyclic one , then our conclusion follows .